# O que são essas informações ao lado do ID do commit?

Tags: git

O que estas informações em vermelho ao lado do ID do commit significam? Percebi que só neste commit há isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não há branch, este log encontra-se no *master*.

Comment: é o seu branch https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ramifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Branching-no-Git-B%C3%A1sico-de-Branch-e-Merge

Comment: Não há branch criado

Comment: tem certeza que isso aí não era um branch que foi mergeado e deletado? se não for também fiquei curioso

Comment: se você roda o seguinte comando `git describe --long --tags` o que retorna?

Comment: Utiliza o Jenkins ou algo do gênero?

Comment: @AlvaroAlves o comando mencionado retorna:

`fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.`

Não utilizo Jenkins.

Comment: @LucasMiranda, realizei outros merges de branches e nenhum ficou com estas informações ao lago do commit

Comment: Isso significa que aquele commit corresponde ao branch feature/chart que está no origin. Para saber qual é o origin, rode `git remote show origin` e veja qual é a *Push URL* e *Fetch URL*

Comment: @hkotsubo obrigado pelo seu comentário, peço que mude-o para uma resposta assim poderei marcar como a solução para a minha dúvida.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`origin/feature/chart` é basicamente o branch chamado `feature/chart` que está no `origin`. Isso significa que aquele commit corresponde a este branch.

> Na verdade é um pouco mais complicado que isso. O `origin/feature/chart` é o que a [documentação](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) chama de "*Remote branch*" (branch remoto), mas apesar do nome ele é local (está na sua máquina, no seu repositório local), e ele só é chamado de "remoto" porque está "ligado" a um branch no repositório remoto. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/398966/112052) tem uma explicação mais completa.

---

Para ver qual é o seu `origin`, rode:

```
git remote show origin
```

A saída será algo do tipo:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: http://alguma.url/repositorio.git
  Push  URL: http://alguma.url/repositorio.git
```

As duas URLs acima (*Fetch URL* e *Push URL*) são os endereços usados quando você roda respectivamente `git fetch` e `git push`, e geralmente são as mesmas ([mas nada impede que sejam diferentes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31747072)).

---

Esta informação aparece quando a [opção `decorate` está habilitada](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git+log+--decorate+). Você pode habilitá-la via linha de comando:

```
git log --decorate
```

Ou colocando esta opção como *default* nas configurações do git:

```
git config --global log.decorate auto
```

Após feita a configuração acima, o `git log` sempre mostre a informação do `decorate` (a menos que você rode `git log --no-decorate`).